# Why -logD trick in GANs training work?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gan, generative-models

When training the generator, we want to minimize log(1 - D(G(z))) (this has a form of log (1-x)). Using [graph calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) we plot and see that the slope of this function is very small at first, thus giving handicaps for G when training in early stages. To solve this, we have to equalize the "minimize log(1 - D(G(z)))" to minimize -log(D(G(z))) (-log x). Using the graph plotter again, we can see the gradient at the early steps is much more stronger.

However, in this graphs plotted, the x value is increasing, while our data is images. Can someone explain the intuition or clarify this point for me? I can still dont understand why inverting to `-log(D(G(z)))` helps Generator learn faster and better.

The plots of two functions:
[image: plots of two functions]

Comment: Can you have a source for the statement that  this transformation increases performance of G?

Comment: If you ever code the standard GAN, you will surely know about the -logD trick. The statement is in the paper from Goodfellow in 2015 as I remember.

Comment: After contemplation, I think I have the answer. As you see, in these figures, we can see if value if x is small, the gradient will be big. At early stages of training, G is weaker than D, so D(G(z)) = x is small. Two functions may work but the blue line give the sharper slope. That is why -logD trick works here. 
Any other explanations are welcome.

Comment: @GiangNguyễn that's exactly how I explained it to myself